# How to create a console inside my code editor which runs python code in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an code editor and my run function is unable to run python script that's why I want to create a console like terminal like other modern code editor have
How to create a console like terminal for python code editor

This is my run function:-

```
def run(event=None):
    global file
    if file == "":
        pass
    else:
        
        command = f"python {file}"
        run_file = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        Output, error = run_file.communicate()
        output.insert(END,f"{file}>>\n")
        output.insert(END,Output)
        output.insert(END,error)
```

this is the error:-

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'D:\\coding'
```

full code (not full code short version of real code focusing only my problem):-

```
import os
import subprocess
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory, askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename


def process_directory(parent,path):
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        abspath = os.path.join(path,i)
        dirv = os.path.isdir(abspath)
        # save the absolute path in "values" option
        oid = tree.insert(parent,END,text=i,open=False,values=(abspath,))
        if dirv:
            process_directory(oid,abspath)
def Open(event=None):
    global path
    for i in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(i)
    path = askdirectory()
    abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
    root_node = tree.insert("",END,text=abspath,open=True)
    process_directory(root_node,abspath)
def select_file(event=None):
    global file
    item = tree.selection()
    # get the absolute path
    file = tree.item(item,"values")[0]
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        editor.delete(1.0,END)
        with open(file,"r") as f:
            editor.insert(1.0,f.read())
def save(event=None):
    global file
    if file == "":
        saveas()
    else:
        item = tree.selection()
    # get the absolute path
        file = tree.item(item,"values")[0]
        filepath = os.path.join(path,file)
        with open(file,"w") as f:
            f.write(editor.get(1.0,END))
        root.title(os.path.basename(file) + "-Python")
def saveas(event=None):
    global file
    file = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".py",filetypes=[("Python Files","*.py")])
    if file == "":
        file = None
    else:
        with open(file,"w") as f:
            f.write(editor.get(1.0,END))
        root.title(os.path.basename(file) + "-Python")
def run(event=None):
    global file
    if file == "":
        pass
    else:
        
        command = f"python {file}"
        run_file = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        Output, error = run_file.communicate()
        output.insert(END,f"{file}>>\n")
        output.insert(END,Output)
        output.insert(END,error)

root = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview()
tree.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)
file = ""
path = ""
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("clam")
style.configure("Treeview",background="gray19",foreground="white",fieldbackground="gray19")
editor = Text(font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",insertbackground="white")
editor.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)
output = Text(height=15,font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",insertbackground="white",insertwidth=10)
output.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)



root.bind("<Control-Alt-o>",Open)
root.bind("<Control-s>",save)
root.bind("<Control-Alt-s>",saveas)
root.bind("<Shift-Return>",run)
tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>",select_file)






root.mainloop()
```

This is the image of my code editor that I have created:-
[image]

Comment: The exception is due to that `file` has space inside: `"D:\coding notes\Code.py"`. So the final command line of `f"python {file}"` will look like `"python D:\coding notes\Code.py"` which means `D:\coding` is the first argument and `notes\Code.py` is the second argument.  You need to surround `file` by double quote: `f'python "{file}"'`.

Comment: Thank you it help me to solve my problem